# Управление cron tab

Tags: php, cron

Какие есть варианты управлением `cron tab` локально средствами php?

Comment: Не знаю, насколько вам это подходит, но в Laravel задачи крона выполняются внутри фреймворка. Системный cron только вызывает одну команду из Laravel раз в минуту. А непосредственно задания ставятся уже внутри фреймворка, с любой периодичностью. Рулятся, соответственно, только через php и БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом простом случае можно воспользоваться скриптом вида

```
<?php
  $content = `crontab -l`;
  $task = $content.'0 0 * * * php ~/www/cron/cron.php'.PHP_EOL;
  file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $task);
  `crontab /tmp/crontab.txt`;
```

Однако, для более удобного управления, с возможностью редактирования и удаления заданий вам возможно более понравится [готовый](https://github.com/MediovskiTechnology/php-crontab-manager) компонент.